# trigger key after x seconds (key is constantly pressed)

Tags: javascript

The code works in the following way: 
- holding shoot/drop button generate bullet and the bomb that is drawn/shown in canvas, 
- it executes all the time in the function draw that refreshes around 60times per second.

Instead I want to set sth as: 
- setInterval(shoot, 1000); 
- setInterval(drop, 2000);

so it should be like: 
- when user presses the key, it creates the bullet/bomb with the interval of 1/2 seconds 
- it should all happen without realising the key

Below I provide the sample code:

```
let left = false;
let up = false;
let right = false;
let down = false;
let shoot = false;
let drop = false;

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) left = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 38) up = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) right = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 40) down = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 17) shoot = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 32) drop = true;
    e.preventDefault();
}
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) left = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 38) up = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) right = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 40) down = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 17) shoot = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 32) drop = false;
    e.preventDefault();
}


function draw() {
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

if (shoot) {
    bullet = new Bullet(player.x - 3, player.y - 3, 6, 10)
    bullets.push(bullet);
}
for (i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
    bullets[i].show();
    bullets[i].move();
}

if (drop) {
    bomb = new Bomb(player.x - 8, player.y + 50, 16, 1)
    bombs.push(bomb);
}
for (i = 0; i < bombs.length; i++) {
    bombs[i].show();     
    bombs[i].move();
}
```

}

```
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Full code on remote server: 
https://stacho163.000webhostapp.com

Is that a way to do it in my code or i have to change the way the buttons work? 
If there is a solution without jQuery, that would be great.

**e: checked the first tip, but after creating the first single bullet/bomb it's working as it was before.**

Thank you for your tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set some sort of wait variable, that indicates that the key is currently pressed, and no processing needs to take place:

```js
let dropping = false;
// indicates that the bomb is dropping right now. Do not drop a new bomb

//...

if (e.keyCode == 32) {
  drop = true;
  dropping = true;
  setTimeout(function () { dropping = false; }, 1000);
  // if 1 second has passed, reset the dropping variable, to allow another bomb to drop
}

//...

if (drop && !dropping) {
    bomb = new Bomb(player.x - 8, player.y + 50, 16, 1)
    bombs.push(bomb);
}
```

This way, your bomb will only drop once every 1 second. Rinse and repeat :)

Comment: Something is wrong. You code works as following: when i press and keep the space nothing happens. After 1 second all the bombs are realised or one bomb is realised and after small gap all are realising. I posted this on remote server that you can inspect the full code and behaviour (main post edited)

Comment: I don't see the wait variable in the code. Can you point it out? I'm looking at https://stacho163.000webhostapp.com/scripts/game.js

Comment: You can't see the wait variable as i've already fixed this. Your code was correct, but i messed up with the proper placement of bomb creation (it has to be made out of the draw loop). Uploaded the newest version so you can take a look, I've just added the setInterval and it seems to be working well. Ofc i accept your answer anyway thx.